# Discord.py Ticket Bot Error: Bot all the time it replies "Sorry, I couldn't find you on the server."

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

```py
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

tickets = {}

class Ticket:

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
        self.channel = None
        self.messages = []
        self.is_closed = False

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command(name='closeticket', description='Close a support ticket')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def close_ticket(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    if member.id in tickets:
        ticket = tickets[member.id]
        if not ticket.is_closed:
            ticket.is_closed = True
            if ticket.channel:
                await ticket.channel.send("This ticket has been closed by the administration.")
                await ticket.channel.delete()
                del tickets[member.id]
                await member.send("Your ticket has been closed.")

            else:
                await ctx.send("The specified user does not have an active ticket to close.")

        else:
            await ctx.send("The specified ticket is already closed.")

    else:
        await ctx.send("The specified user does not have an active ticket.")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel) and not message.author.bot:
        if message.author.id not in tickets:
            guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, id=SERVER_ID) 
            if guild:
                member = guild.get_member(message.author.id)
                if member:
                    new_ticket = Ticket(message.author)
                    overwrites = {
                        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                        member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)

                    }
                    new_ticket.channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'ticket-{message.author.display_name}', overwrites=overwrites)
                    tickets[message.author.id] = new_ticket
                    await message.author.send("Your ticket has been opened automatically. A support team member will be with you shortly.")

                else:
                    await message.author.send("Sorry, I couldn't find you on the server.")
            else:
                await message.author.send("Sorry, I couldn't find the server.")
        else:
            ticket = tickets[message.author.id]
            if ticket.channel and not ticket.is_closed:
                ticket.messages.append(message)
                await ticket.channel.send(f'**{message.author.display_name}:** {message.content}')

            else:
                await message.author.send("Your ticket is not yet assigned to a support channel or has been closed.")
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    if isinstance(after.channel, discord.TextChannel) and after.channel in [t.channel for t in tickets.values()] and not after.author.bot:
        ticket = next((t for t in tickets.values() if t.channel == after.channel), None)
        if ticket:
            user = ticket.user
            user_dm = user.dm_channel or await user.create_dm()
            await user_dm.send(f'**Support:** {after.content}')
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

I tried everything that came to my mind. Expected is the following result:

1. The user sends a DM to the bot
2. The bot creates a channel on the server and sends this message there
3. The server admin sends a message on the bot channel
4. The bot forwards the message as a DM back to the person who contacted it
5. Actions of the !closeticket {user} command (it works)

Comment: You need to enable member intents